Conflict of asynchronous functions over Canvas Context
I tried developing a graph drawing web app using a canvas which includes animations for lines as this:
function animateLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    const nrFrames = 30;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const dx = x2 - x1;
    const incx = dx / nrFrames;
    const incy = dy / nrFrames;
    let tmpx = x1, tmpy = y1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(11, 158, 131, 0.4)';
    for (let i = 0; i < nrFrames; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            tmpx += incx;
            tmpy += incy;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
            ctx.lineTo(tmpx, tmpy);
            ctx.stroke();
        }, i * 16);
    }
}

But also for circles as this:
class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, radius, name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.name = name;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(110, 255, 255)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText(this.name, this.x, this.y);
    }
}

Given the shared context and the fact that the functions have to run asynchronously, the strokes never have the intended color.
I see that I could add strokeStyle = '...' on the line exactly above every stroke made, but I don't believe that's the best solution since with a lot of asychronous functions you will never have a guarantee.
Put in general terms: how is the problem of different style requirements for asychronous functions that use the same context managed?

The answers are answering to 2 questions:

When there are asynchronous functions running, how do you know that one of them doesn't change the strokeStyle before you get to stroke() with the style you wanted.

The answer is that JS is blocking. Thank you, Blindman67.

How do you manage different strokeStyle settings in async functions so that your code is well tied together and makes when you follow it.

Thank you, Helder Sepulveda.
Both of them are equally valuable for someone learning animations in Javascript, so let the fight in the answers come to an end.

Hi Andrei... there was no fight, just some passionate debate ... but now that you truly understand the root cause you could help in that debate clarify some of the points brought up

requestAnimationFrame
Use a main loop to render all animated content.
The main loop is called a frame in frontend JS as it draws only one frame at a time. You request a frame using requestAnimationFrame.
Timer events (setTimeout, setInterval) are very inaccurate and should not be relied upon to drive high quality animations.
Blocking
Javascript execution is blocking. That is no JavaScript code will execute while existing code is executing.
Thus if you have
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
ctx.fill();

it is impossible for any code to change the fillStyle before the fill call is called.
In your code you use the timer events. When you call setTimeout the execution continues, and the function exits and execution context is over. While waiting for the timer events other code can run because nothing is blocking the execution.
Animation using requestAnimationFrame
Showing that timer events (and any event) can not interrupt executing code and change the value of a "shared" context.
The function setStrokeStyle will count number of times that ctx.strokeStyle is red. Never as the only time it is red in the example is in the execution of mainLoop (which can not be interrupted).
Example below animates a line using requestAnimationFrame.

The animation time is 2 seconds starting as sone and the first animation frame is called.
The time is automatically passed to the animation frame.
A timer event is generated every 5 ms that sets the stroke style to green.
The animation draws a red line which can not be changed by the timer event.



requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff"; // signals setStrokeStyle 
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y});           // point x, y 
const L2 = (p1 = P2(), p2 = P2()) => ({p1, p2}); // line from 2 points p1, p2

const lineA = L2(P2(0, 0), P2(300, 300)); // Line start position
const lineB = L2(P2(0, 300), P2(300, 0)); // line end position
const animTime = 2;  // time in seconds
var startTime;       // time in ms or undefined
var endTime;         // time in ms or undefined

function animateLine(fromLine, toLine, unitTime) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    const f = fromLine;  // alias for readability
    const t = toLine;    // alias for readability
    const u = unitTime;   // alias for readability
    const l = L2(
        P2((t.p1.x - f.p1.x) * u + f.p1.x, (t.p1.y - f.p1.y) * u + f.p1.y),
        P2((t.p2.x - f.p2.x) * u + f.p2.x, (t.p2.y - f.p2.y) * u + f.p2.y)
    );
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(l.p1.x, l.p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(l.p2.x, l.p2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";  // signals setStrokeStyle

}

var count = 0;
// Function sets strokeStyle every ~5ms to show that it 
// can not change the animation style
function setStrokeStyle() {
    // Is stroke not blue or green then display interrupted execution 
    if (ctx.strokeStyle !== "#0000ff" && ctx.strokeStyle !== "#008000") {  
                                        // Will never happen
                                        // as execution can not interrupt
                                        // execution of mainLoop
                                        // the only place in this 
                                        // example that sets
                                        // ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000"
                                        
        // Will never happen                                         
        showCountDiv.textContent = "Execution interrupted: " + (count ++);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green"; // set to "#008000"
    setTimeout(setStrokeStyle, 5);

}
setStrokeStyle(); // start setting stroke style





function mainLoop(time) {
    if (startTime === undefined) {
        startTime = time;
        endTime = time + animTime * 1000;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if (time > endTime) {
        startTime = undefined;  // resets animation
    } else {
        animateLine(lineA, lineB, (time - startTime) / (animTime * 1000));
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
}
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="showCountDiv">Not interupted</div>




I think you probably didn't fully understand his question... The author is not talking about animation, but about the collision of styles in a shared context. So I will be so kind as to remind you once again of the Author's question: Put in general terms: how is the problem of different style requirements for asynchronous functions that use the same context managed?

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz JavaScript is blocking! The style can only be accessed by one execution context at the time. My example shows that the timer event setStrokeStyle that fires every ~5ms can not change the "shared" 2D context while mainLoop is executing.  Asynchronous functions only run one at a time, they can not run while existing code is running. This is fundamental to JS execution model...

My friend, I don't want to get into a pointless discussion with you so as not to irritate the Moderators. His problem, or rather I would call it a hypothetical problem, was clear to me and clear to Colleague, who also provided the answer... Apparently we are thinking about different contexts, you about another, we about another, in the general context of this question... Have a good day...

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz  "hypothetical problem" s are off topic and should be closed and you should not answer question you consider hypothetical (consider voting to close such questions). Though I do not see the question as hypothetical (the code is part of a real world app). It is clear that the OP does not understand the concept of blocking code. Please take the time to review your understanding of JS execution context and blocking code,

I like your use of class in the circle but do not like what you are doing in animateLine it looks like those two are written by two different developers, with much different years of experience...
...not going to re-explain requestAnimationFrame, Blindman67 did a great job in his answer there, read that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78565281/7599833
Yes Timer events are inaccurate, but my experience you can create good enough animations.

I would build a Line class, something like this:
class Line {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.data.color;
        ctx.moveTo(this.data.x1, this.data.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.data.x2, this.data.y2);
        ctx.stroke();        
    }
}

Very similar to what you have in the circle, one constructor that sets the initial values and a draw method where we draw everything related to this one object, you can add other methods later
... this way we can create multiple lines instances and animate them with setInterval:
lines = [
  new Line({x1:0,y1:0, x2:100,y2:100, color:"red"}),
  new Line({x1:0,y1:50, x2:200,y2:100, color:"cyan"})
]
setInterval(() => {
  lines[0].data.x2 += 1
}, 200)

Then the animation/movement will be completely separate from the drawing, we can set different speeds for the animation, or not move at all, on that example I'm moving the first line to grow on the X axis slowly
We move in the intervals and draw in the main loop
    function mainLoop() {
      ctx.reset();
      lines.forEach(l => l.draw(ctx));
      circles.forEach(c => c.draw(ctx));
      requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }


I simplified a lot your code, to keep it nice and short, that way it fits better in one snippet


class Circle {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.data.color;
        ctx.arc(this.data.x, this.data.y, this.data.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();        
    }
}

class Line {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.data.color;
        ctx.moveTo(this.data.x1, this.data.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.data.x2, this.data.y2);
        ctx.stroke();        
    }
}

lines = [
  new Line({x1:0,y1:0, x2:100,y2:100, color:"red"}),
  new Line({x1:0,y1:50, x2:200,y2:100, color:"cyan"})
]
setInterval(() => {
  lines[0].data.x2 += 1
}, 200)


counter = 0
circles = [
  new Circle({x: 100, y: 50, radius: 20, color:"black"}),
  new Circle({x: 95, y: 45, radius: 6, color:"blue"})
]
setInterval(() => {
  counter++
  circles[1].data.x += Math.sin(counter)*4 
  circles[1].data.y += Math.cos(counter)*4
}, 50)


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function mainLoop() {
  ctx.reset();
  lines.forEach(l => l.draw(ctx));
  circles.forEach(c => c.draw(ctx));
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="160"></canvas>



You can see here the red line move slow and the inner blue circle spins a lot faster, all different colors and no conflict, if you want to do more complex cases you should look into game engines, there are many good open source ones:
https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

There are basically two options: synchronizing the different parts that draw something or actually putting strokeStyle = ... before each .stroke() statement.
If you want to synchronize the code, you will need a centralized draw() function that calls all dependant draw() functions in turns. This makes sure they do not interfere with each other (like changing the color).
Synchronizing is definitely a bit more complex but the code will be much cleaner ultimately. For your animation this would mean you cannot use setTimeout in this way anymore.

Javascript is blocking, there is no need to put strokeStyle near stroke as long as they are in the same execution context. -1
